# Passing variables from javascript to php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have worked on API (zomato) that gives me restaurant details. I want to insert them into my local database, but I have a problem with passing the variable to PHP because it's too much big for $_GET to handle it. I tried to use $_POST but The output of the post was empty.

// JS code

```
function showCafes(str){
     var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log(str);
  xhttp.open("GET","https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_type=city&q=t&start="+str+"&count=20" , true);
  xhttp.send();
  var restaurants="";
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var r=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 var rest ={
      name : r.restaurant[1].restaurant.name
     };
    $.post("addFromApi.php", rest);
     window.location.href="addFromApi.php";
```

// PHP code

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I expected from the PHP code to print the name of the first element in it.
// Sample output From API

```
{"results_found":1,
"results_start":0,
"results_shown":1,
"restaurants":
[{"restaurant":{
"R":{"res_id":18692654},
"id":"18692654",
"name":"East Village"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with making a form from js like this

```
     document.getElementById("cafes").innerHTML += '<form id="rests" action="addFromApi.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="q" value="'+restaurants+'"></form>';
document.getElementById("rests").submit();
//resturants is the variable that I wanted to pass to php.
```